# mysql Many to Many Relationship as Columns

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have the following structure:

```
case:
id int
...

behaviours:
id int,
label varchar

case_to_behaviour:
case_id,
behaviour_id
```

The Behaviours is a set list, it does not get dynamically added or edited or deleted by the users.

there are a number of Many to Many relationships like this which i need to report on, but getting this one right would give me a template to work with the rest of them.

So far, because there is only 8 listed 'behaviours' i have the following query which gets me what i want, how ever i am hoping maybe there is a nicer or more efficient way to query this.

The data need to be present like so:

```
id | behaviour_1 | behaviour_2 | behaviour_3 | behaviour_4 | behaviour_5 ....
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | true        | true        | false       | false       | true
```

The script which i currently use to get his is as followed, but will only work up to 9 possible items.

```
SELECT 
    case.id,
    IF(csb.behaviours like '%1%', true, false) as `behaviour_1`,
    IF(csb.behaviours like '%2%', true, false) as `behaviour_2`,
    IF(csb.behaviours like '%3%', true, false) as `behaviour_3`,
    IF(csb.behaviours like '%4%', true, false) as `behaviour_4`,
    IF(csb.behaviours like '%5%', true, false) as `behaviour_5`,
    IF(csb.behaviours like '%6%', true, false) as `behaviour_6`,
    IF(csb.behaviours like '%7%', true, false) as `behaviour_7`,
    IF(csb.behaviours like '%8%', true, false) as `behaviour_8`

from case c
left join 
    (select group_concat(behaviour_id) as behaviours, case_id  from case_to_behavior group by case_id) csb on csb.case_id=c.id
group by c.id;
```

EDIT:
I have tried a similar query as demonstraight below, how ever it only works for the first join, which makes sense. i just don't know how to get the data in the format i want.

```
SELECT 
    case.id,
    IF(csb.behaviour_id = 1, true, false) as `behaviour_1`,
    IF(csb.behaviour_id = 2, true, false) as `behaviour_2`,
    IF(csb.behaviour_id = 3, true, false) as `behaviour_3`,
    IF(csb.behaviour_id = 4, true, false) as `behaviour_4`,
    IF(csb.behaviour_id = 5, true, false) as `behaviour_5`,
    IF(csb.behaviour_id = 6, true, false) as `behaviour_6`,
    IF(csb.behaviour_id = 7, true, false) as `behaviour_7`,
    IF(csb.behaviour_id = 8, true, false) as `behaviour_8`,
from case c
left join case_to_behavior csb on csb.case_id=c.id
group by c.id;
```

Comment: `group by c.id` is redundant in outer query, since you are already doing group by in inner query. and ideally `case` master table shouldn't be having duplicate `id`s

Comment: Suppose if you evaluate 10th case, `csb.behaviours like '%10%'` and `csb.behaviours like '%1%'` will both evaluate to `true` and `behaviour_1` and `behaviour_10` will both be `true`

Comment: Yes. This is the main issue im trying to circumvent as i do have other joins where this will be an issue.

i have tried just a normal left join, and then checking that the behaviour id's exit, how ever this seems to only work for the first instance, which makes sense.

eg Select case.id, IF(csb.behavior_id == 1, TRUE, FALSE) from case  c left join case_to_behaviour csb on csb.case_id = c.id

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out:

```
SELECT 
    case.id,
    sum(IF(csb.behaviour_id = 1, true, false)) as `behaviour_1`,
    sum(IF(csb.behaviour_id = 2, true, false)) as `behaviour_2`,
    sum(IF(csb.behaviour_id = 3, true, false)) as `behaviour_3`,
    sum(IF(csb.behaviour_id = 4, true, false)) as `behaviour_4`,
    sum(IF(csb.behaviour_id = 5, true, false)) as `behaviour_5`,
    sum(IF(csb.behaviour_id = 6, true, false)) as `behaviour_6`,
    sum(IF(csb.behaviour_id = 7, true, false)) as `behaviour_7`,
    sum(IF(csb.behaviour_id = 8, true, false)) as `behaviour_8`,
from case c
left join case_to_behavior csb on csb.case_id=c.id
group by c.id;
```